# Is it possible to imitate keyboard behaviour with selenium?

Tags: java, scala, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im automating something and one thing i have issue with is an auto-complete dropdown where im sending a string key to, but then i need to choose from the drop down a value to select it, and I have to actually click on it.

So I wanted to know if its possible after that im sending the key to:

> go down one time (with the "down" arrow in the keyboard)

then

> click enter

is that possible?

I can use java or scala

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that by following code :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(""); //HERE GIVE ID OF THAT YOUR ELEMENT & YOU CAN DO SENDKEYS WITH IT IF REQUIRE
element.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN); // IT WILL PRESS DOWN KEY
element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); // IT WILL PRESS ENTER KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, see [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) and [Selenium Actions Class](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html).
e.g. you may try

Java(for Enter Key)

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Value")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Value")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

And for Down

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Value")).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
```